# Detecting connection on Windows Phone 8 with Sencha+PhoneGap

Tags: windows-phone-8, sencha-touch-2, cordova

I'm trying to detect whether a connection is available on my Sencha Touch+PhoneGap app that's running on Windows Phone 8. Problem is, any check I make (using both `Ext.device.Connection.isOnline()` from Sencha and `navigator.network.connection` from PhoneGap) results in the state of the connection when the app was launched. I do have `ID_CAP_NETWORKING` checked on WMAppManifest.xml, by the way.

So if I launched the app while there was no connection, Ext.device.Connection.isOnline() and navigator.network.connection will both always say that there is no connection, even if I get a connection while the app is running. If I launched the app while there was a connection, even if I lose the connection the calls will always say that there is a connection.

I have a hack for this (using simple ajax calls and seeing if they fail), but it's definitely not a great solution. Has anyone else encountered this problem? I have limited understanding of this part of mobile development and really don't even know where to start.

Comment: Did you try the phonegap online and offline events? Are they working or are they broken too? I didn't tested it yet, but I saw them in API documentation

Comment: Just tried that. Phonegap online and offline events did work as spec'd, but the unfortunate thing was if the connection changed while the app was disabled (lock screen, not being viewed, etc), it wouldn't pick up on the change. Great suggestion though!